# Grouping first by Column C and then Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel, I have Column A1 (string [name]), B2(float[price]) and C3(numeric[date]). Below is in example:

```
A1 B2  C3 
A 100 2001 
B 123 2001 
B 227 1999 
B 299 1999 
A 039 2001
C 300 2001
```

I want to sort this into groups to give the total expenses for each person for each year - imagine that each row is an expense claim. I want the data to look something like this:

```
A1 B2  C3 
A 139 2001 
B 123 2001
B 526 1999
C 300 2001
```

I have zero experience with excel and cannot simply import it into an SQL database for security reasons that I won't go into.

I'd like to do the above on a HUGE spreadsheet of data such as the above. I understand I'll need to tailor the solution to my own needs but I have literally no idea where to start as I have no experience with excel. I did some googling which pointed me at things like subtotals which doesn't quite sort the data into a clean table for me.

I know this so do-able in SQL with GROUP BY - is there some kind of equivalent in excel? If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks so much in advance,

P.S. This is my first post, go easy on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a pivot table. "insert, pivot table" and choose new tab then you'll get an empty pivot table.  You can drag fields from the field picker at the top to the rows and values boxes to decide how things are sliced and diced.

A picture is probably easier to describe the sequence - after inserting a new pivot table, I dragged A1 from the top right, into the rows box in the bottom right:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, skipping the step of creating a data table first will severely limit future analysis, data manipulation, and complicate updates.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy for you.

1. Convert your data to an Excel Data Table `Insert > Table`. Just make sure your data is contiguous (no blank rows or cells) or highlight all of it, and check the header row box, as appropriate.
2. Create a Pivot Table from your Data Table.  With a cell in your data table highlighted, select `Insert Pivot Table`.  Use the default for data to analyze, and choose your location to meet your needs.
3. Setup your Pivot Table with:
   `Rows` = Name, Date
   `Values` = Sum of Price
4. Format your Pivot Table to taste (e.g. turn off subtotals for Name, sort by Date descending, layout as Tabular).